# What does arr[:,[1,0,2] means in the snippet of code?

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I was doing numpy, and this is how they were swapping columns 1 and 2 in an array.

```py
arr[:, [1,0,2]]
```

Here, what does `[1,0,2]` means?

Comment: Have you tried [reading the documentation?](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing)

Comment: Column ordering during selection the original had 0,1,2 now over to 1,0,2

Comment: This is indexing the 2nd (last) dimension ('columns')

Answer (score 0):

It means select the items at index 1, 0, and 2 in this dimension/axis; in that order.

Answer (score 0):

here [1,0,2] takes the order in which columns of the arr should be re-arranged i.e the column at index [1] , then column at index [0] and finally the column at index [2] should be ordered while rows' order remains the same.